# onClick Listener Inside Loop Android Studio map marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps, loops, android-studio

When clicking on the infoWindow i pass the same 'currentStall' for each click.
It must be creating only one instance of the click listener.  'currentStall' passes a unique identifier to the location clicked but passes only the last in the array and not each separate identifier.

```
Iterator<Stall> iter = stalls.listIterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                final Stall currentStall = iter.next();

                String stallId = currentStall.getId().get$Oid();
                Double x = currentStall.getLocation().getCoordinates().get(0);
                Double y = currentStall.getLocation().getCoordinates().get(1);
                final String myName = currentStall.getName();
                addCircle(new LatLng(y, x), currentStall.getRadius(), 0);

                LatLng CIU = new LatLng(y, x);

                Marker cmumarker;
                cmumarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(CIU)
                        .title(myName)
                        .flat(true)
                        .snippet(currentStall.getId().get$Oid()));
                cmumarker.showInfoWindow();

                mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker cmumarker){
                        //Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AdminActivity.class);
                        //startActivity(intent);
                        Intent intent = new Intent("life.stall.StallBox");
                        startActivity(intent);
                        App appState = ((App) getApplicationContext());
                        appState.setCurStall(currentStall);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), myName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Maps `setOnInfoWindowClickListener()` method does replace the `OnInfoWindowClickListener`, so what you're seeing is the correct behaviour.

To associate each `Marker` with the appropriate `Stall`, you could use a `HashMap` which you declare outside your `while` loop:

```
HashMap<Marker, Stall> stallLookup = new HashMap<Marker, Stall>();
```

Then you can populate it in your loop after you've setup `cmumarker`:

```
stallLookup.put(cmumarker, currentStall);
```

Then in your `OnInfoWindowClickListener`, you just lookup the `Stall` in the map:

```
Stall currentStall = stallLookup.get(cmumarker);
```